# Netgear smart switches - how view MAC address of devices connected to each port?

Tags: networking, router, lan

Im setting a VLAN on a remote site i do not easy have access to.

There are 3 switches daisy chained (Netgear GS716Tv3, Netgear GS105Ev2, Netgear GS108PEv3, and a router (Draytek 2860) forming the LAN.

Im familiar with the network typology in terms of which switch daisy chains into the router and into each other, but i don't know which ports are used, so i don't know which ports to make Trunk ports.

I have the MAC addresses of all the switches and the router, but i couldn't find a way to view all the ports on the switch and see their connected devices MAC.

Is that possible on the Netgear switches ?

I tried to go to `System > Device View` on the web GUI but it says i need a Java browser plugin to be installed and [Chrome on OSX dosn't allow Java plugins, nor dose Firefox or Safari.](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml)

Im on Mac OSX so i cant install the Netgear Plus Configuration utility.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell only about M4300-52G. Perhaps you can find MAC addresses of connected devices by the following path by the menu: Switching -> Address table. There is a filter by VLAN and some other options.